# Best REST Client Framework/Utility on Android

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm about to build an Android application that will use a RESTful Web Service. I don't want to write the REST client by myself, as I want it to be as effective and stable as possible (this is the first time I'm using REST).

Are there any (free) frameworks or utilities avaibale for Android/Java that I can use in my project?

Comment: SOAPUI can make REST calls, does that help?

Comment: For what I understand SOAPUI is a framework for testning? I also need support for JSON.

Comment: There is source code for a rest client on this page + some help, (it is for jira but should be usable for android as well) http://www.j-tricks.com/1/post/2012/05/java-rest-client-for-jira-using-jersey.html

Comment: Volley is suggested by Google. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: Personally I'm quite a big fan of Volley. It's offically supported in the Android Docs.
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html
https://github.com/google/volley

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[Restlet](http://restlet.org) is an excellent REST framework and has an Android edition.

Comment: Restlet looks promising. I will definitely try it out. Thanks!

Comment: as good as it may be. I cant warrant changing a 0.3MB APK into 22MB with all these added files

Comment: @Doomsknight it's called Proguard

Comment: Use Volley .</br>
[https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728] Google I/O Session

Library Link
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley<br>

and [http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/]a simple blog which explains how to use it

Answer (score 4):

Any HTTP Client library should be perfectly adequate to interact RESTfully with a web API.   E.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Comment: To the downvoter, feel free to explain why HTTPClient is insufficient to interact with a RESTful system who's core constraint is conforming to the "Uniform Interface" which in this case is defined by RFC2616.

Comment: I wasn't the down voter, but I would imagine it could be because HttpClient only solves part of the problem, then you've got all that XML handling to do. Maybe HttpClient + SAX, or HttpClient and XmlPullParser would be a more complete answer. YMMV

Comment: Darrel: I have tried Apache's HTTPClient. But as i said, I do not want to write the complete REST client by myself.

Comment: mezmo: thanks for the tip, but I'm looking for something more complete. I would like to write code like this:

Object response = RestClient.get("http://example.com/api/news");

or


Object response = RestClient.delete("http://example.com/api/news", 20);

Comment: @Gustav sigh.  I guess this http://crest.codegist.org/android.html is exactly what you are looking for.  But please remember, what you are doing will not give you the benefits of REST.  If you don't mind, that's cool.

Answer (score 4):

try out Spring Android - is has very handy class RestTemplate.

Comment: Triggers a lot of GC_CONCURRENT for me, does it have some memory issues ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm also looking for a SMALL solution for rest client on Android. After a quick comparison, I found:

- **Resting** v0.7: resting-0.7-dev-release-android.jar - **1.3MB** (all-in-one according to
  the doc)
- **Restlet** v2.1.2: org.restlet.jar - **728KB** (however must > 1MB after adding httpclient extention and json extention)
- **Spring for Android** v1.0.1: spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar 113KB + spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar 186KB + gson-2.2.3.jar 194KB = **493KB** (without auth support, otherwise spring social will be a dependency)

Please correct me if any miss.

Comment: Note that Restlet 2.2 now contains a much lighter core (org.restlet.jar) for Android, reusing the HttpURLConnection class by default. The Apache HTTP Client extension is purely optional.

Comment: Actual org.restlet.jar file size in version 2.2.1 of Android edition is only 668 Kb. No additional dependency required. http://maven.restlet.org/org/restlet/android/org.restlet/2.2.1/

Comment: @JeromeLouvel, so the new version of restlet has built-in httpclient & json support?

Comment: The new version has merged the org.restlet.ext.net extension into the org.restlet core. We moved the previous internal HTTP connector to the NIO extension, reducing the size of org.restlet core significantly. For JSON, it isn't in the core as it depends on how you need to process it.

Comment: In version 2.3 of Restlet, we are also planning on adding a client-side profile for the "org.restlet" module so save additional size (by removing all server-specific code).

Comment: @JeromeLouvel, good news to me, I'll definitely have a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check out Resting - "Lightweight Java component to consume REST service and transform response into objects"

http://code.google.com/p/resting/

i haven't used it myself, but i plan to.

to go along with it, i'm searching for example source code to implement the best practices described in this google IO session. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Comment: +1 for the google IO session!

Comment: Seems that resting is not receiving any development and fails to POST data to a REST service.

Comment: @Rene Looks like an update was just pushed to address this issue: https://code.google.com/p/resting/source/detail?r=123