# How do I communicate with a REST API using Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, rest, android-studio

Afternoon,

I am new to the forums so please go easy.

I am looking to code a java package within an android application that will GET, POST, UPDATE and DELETE to a Trading REST API. https://labs.ig.com/gettingstarted is this possible using the HttpClient library within Java. I haven’t found much in the realm of tutorials, does Android have a library that I could use?

I appreciate any pointers.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: Is this possible within the Java API's it seems like it should be standard functionality but can't find anything in the Java tutorial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best REST Client Framework/Utility on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945119/best-rest-client-framework-utility-on-android)

Comment: You can use Retrofit library by Square (http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It is the easiest way IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd look into either:

Retrofit
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

```
public interface GitHubService {
  @GET("/users/{user}/repos")
  List<Repo> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .build();

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);

List<Repo> repos = service.listRepos("octocat");
```

Ion https://github.com/koush/ion

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("foo", "bar");

Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/post")
.setJsonObjectBody(json)
.asJsonObject()
.setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
   @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
        // do stuff with the result or error
    }
});
```

Whichever you prefer. You can even mix Spring-Android or Retrofit with `RoboSpice` as per https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples and it'll handle the background-thread stuff for you for the download.

Comment: Apparently you can make it even fancier using Retrofit with *RxJava*: http://www.node.mu/2014/07/02/using-retrofit-and-rxjava-to-interact-with-web-services-on-android/

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Spring RestTemplate for android](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/), it's good enough for REST.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into implementing this within my Android application.